# Regular expression to capture windows paths or filenames starting with X:\ **enclosed or not** by quotes to have spaces in it

Tags: regex, parsing, tokenize, regex-lookarounds

I need to build a regular expression to capture one or more windows paths inside a text. It's for a syntax highlighter.

Imagine this text:

```
Hey, Bob!

I left you the report for tomorrow in D:\Files\Shares\report.pdf along
with the other reports.

There's also this pptx here D:\Files\Internal\source.pptx where you have
the original if you need to change anything.

Cheers!
Alice.
```

This one is easy to capture with `/[a-zA-Z]:\\[^\s]*/mg`. See it in regex101 here https://regex101.com/r/VcBV7M/1

[image: Capturing sample 1]

## Nevertheless

when the path has spaces like here:

```
I left you the report for tomorrow in D:\Shared files\october report.pdf along
with the other reports.
```

then we run into problems: What is the path? `D:\Shared` or `D:\Shared files\october` or `D:\Shared files\october report.pdf` or `D:\Shared files\october report.pdf along`...

For a human it's simple to infer. For a computer it's impossible so I was thinking into forcing the users to use quotes or brackets to indicate the begin and end of the filename or path.

## Question

How can I write a regex that given this:

```
Hey, Bob!

I left you the report for tomorrow in "D:\Shared files\october report.pdf" along
with the other reports [Don't forget to add your punctuation]. See
also D:\Multifiles\charlie.docx for more info.

There's also this pptx here [D:\Internal files\source for report.pptx] where you have
the original if you need to change "anything like the boss wants".

Cheers!
Alice.
```

captures this?

```
D:\Shared files\october report.pdf
D:\Multifiles\charlie.docx
D:\Internal files\source for report.pptx
```

but not

```
Don't forget to add your punctuation
anything like the boss wants
```

Non-working sample: https://regex101.com/r/RGVPz6/2

Comment: It is next to impossible to match arbitrary file paths inside longer text. You can get an approximate solution, but none will be 100% safe.

Comment: I re-added the tag `regex-lookarounds`. It was removed, but it's "the real key" to the potential solution to this question.

Comment: This article could help https://es.javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind but I don't quite know how to use lookarounds in regexes.

Comment: “For a human it's simple to infer.” — Not always, which is precisely also why it‘s impossible to infer for an algorithm. Consider the (slightly ungrammatical but entirely plausible) sentence “Go to folder C:\foo\bar and baz.txt is the file you want”. Does this refer to a file `baz.txt` in a folder `bar`, or is the filename `bar and baz.txt`, in folder `foo`? Both are equally plausible.

Comment: Agree. This is why I asked to recognize sorrounding delimiters. Already anwered by myself, though.  “Go to folder [C:\foo\bar and baz.txt] is the file you want” does not present any ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that lookahead and lookbehind helped.

The expression is: `(?<=\[)[a-zA-Z]:\\.*(?=])|(?<=")[a-zA-Z]:\\.*(?=")|([a-zA-Z]:\\[^\s]*)`

Here's the solution online-live-edit https://regex101.com/r/RGVPz6/3

The key parts are:

- In the first option `(?<=\[)` and `(?=])` tell to only match if the string is exactly surrounded by `[` and `]`.
- In the second option `(?<=")` and `(?=")` tell to only match if the string is exactly surrounded by `"` and `"`.
- The third option is the old one.

See it working:

[image: Solution]

PD: Inspired here https://es.javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind

Answer (score 0):

If you have boundaries like `".."` `[..]` or matching only non whitespace characters:

```
\b(?:(?<=\[)[a-z]:\\[^]]*(?=])|(?<=")[a-z]:\\[^"]*(?=")|[a-z]:\\\S+)
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?<=\[)[a-z]:\\[^]]*(?=])` Between `[...]` match a-z `:\` then match optional chars other than `]` using a negated character class
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<=")[a-z]:\\[^"]*(?=")` Between `"..."` match a-z `:\` then match optional chars other than `"` using a negated character class
  - `|` Or
  - `[a-z]:\\\S+` Match a-z `:\` and then 1+ non whitespace chars
- `)` Close the non capture group

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gi1IhS/1).

Comment: If a path contains a dot (say, `D:\Product\7.0\abc.gif`) the `[a-zA-Z]:\\.*?\.\w+` [won't work](https://regex101.com/r/ZskTKh/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, it is best effort due to the allowed spaces in the pattern. Maybe listing the extensions makes it a bit better.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew a simple [change](https://regex101.com/r/dqmRe0/1) fixes your issue. You can keep breaking it still, of course, but this is fuzzy matching to start with, at some point you just have to say "good enough".

Comment: A file could have not any extension at all, or be a folder name, like `D:\Saved files\listing` or have an unknown newer extension like `D:\Saved files\listing.gsheet`. The key is to use the delimiters like `"xxx"` or `[xxx]` that remove any ambiguity.

Comment: @XaviMontero I see what you mean and updated the answer.